# IO reading (java)

Tags: java, io

if i have a loop like so:

```
    while(st.hasMoreTokens() )
    {



            array[i] = st.nextToken();
            array[(i+1)] = st.nextToken();


            i++;
    }
```

will array[i] and array[i+1] end up having the same word or will it put one word in array[i] and the next word in array[i+1]? i'm trying to read in 2 words at a time until my line runs out of words. 
Thanks.

Comment: that could crash, you're not checking if there is a token in the second call.

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: call `hasMoreTokens` again; or be lazy and assume your input is correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will "will it put one word in `array[i]` and the next word in `array[i+1]`".

Note that `nextToken()` returns the next token from `st` string tokenizer. Be careful about the `NoSuchElementException` - if there are no more tokens in `st` tokenizer's string.

Try something like this:

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens() )
{
    array[i] = st.nextToken();
    if(st.hasMoreTokens()) // check again whether the next toaken is available or not
        array[(i+1)] = st.nextToken();
    i++;
}
```